# Redirect FTP requests

Tags: mysql, dns, ftp, port

I have an application that connects to a domain using port 3306 (MySQL) and port 21 (FTP).

I've had to move the MySQL hosting to another server (AWS) and need to keep the FTP server as is.

Now the problem I have is that the application doesn't allow you to specify a different server name for each service so it's trying to connect via FTP to the MySQL server in AWS.

Is there any way to setup Windows to redirect certain ports only to a different IP?

Is there a way to set up the new server to bounce FTP requests back to the older server?

Alternatively is there a way to setup the domain DNS to point MySQL port requests to the MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to fix this is, install a TCP proxy server (Eg. nginx, haproxy) on the new server and pass the request to the old server based on the request type.

Comment: The web panel I currently use on the new server only allows Squid Proxy Server , would this be sufficient?

Comment: squid is a http web caching proxy. It won't be helpful in your case.